# How access an array in a Dictionary in a plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

i have 2 arrays in a dictionary stored as a plist.i am not able to find a way to access these arrays separately

```
<key>MainCategories</key>
<dict>
  <key>CategoryNames</key>
    <array>
        <string>Accelaration</string>
        <string>Force</string>
        <string>Fuel Consumption</string>
    </array>
    <key>Images</key>
    <array>
        <string>accelaration_icon.png</string>
        <string>force_icon.png</string>
        <string>fuel_icon.png</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After loading the plist, you just access the different keys:

```
NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filename];

NSDictionary *mainCategories = [plist objectForKey:@"MainCategories"];
NSArray *categoryNames = [mainCategories objectForKey:@"CategoryNames"];
NSArray *images = [mainCategories objectForKey:@"Images"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *plistFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathOfResource:@".." ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *mainCategories = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistFilePath];

NSArray *categoryNames = [mainCategories objectForKey:@"CategoryNames"];
NSArray *categoryImages = [mainCategories objectForKey:@"Images"];
```